# Indicar el archivo que tiene la clave privada cuando conecto a servidor remoto vía ssh

Tags: ssh

Necesito indicar en mi equipo local que el servidor remoto escuche las conexiones de `localhost`en el puerto `3307`:

En el equipo local tengo una clave privada para autentificarme, sin tener que usar la contraseña. Dicho archivo se llamaba al inicio `id_dsa` y conectaba bien usando el comando de más abajo.  El problema es que he generado otro archivo en mi hosting el cual ahora se llama `id_rsa.dms`.

Cuando intento conectar como siempre lo he hecho con:

```
ssh -vvv -f usuario@ip-remota -L 3307:localhost:3306 -N
```

No llego a conectarme al servidor remoto.

**¿Cómo puedo indicar que el archivo donde están la clave privada es `id_rsa.dms`?**

Este es el debug completo del intento de conexión:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "mi-ip" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to mi-ip [mi-ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to mi-ip:22 as 'ssh-user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/mi-user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/mi-user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from mi-ip
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,c....
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-...
debug2: ciphers ctos: ...
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<8192<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 4107/8192
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:...
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/mi-user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /Users/mi-user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from mi-ip
debug1: Host 'mi-ip' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/mi-user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug2: bits set: 4091/8192
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7fc36f40a9f0)
debug2: key: /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/mi-user/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ssh-user@mi-ip's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
Authentication failed.
```

Comment: @Marcos el archivo se genera desde el cPanel del hosting y luego lo descargo. Solo que ahora se genera como `id_rsa.dms`. Antes no tenía esa extensión y funcionaba.  Intenté quitarle el `.dms` y tampoco funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la manera de hacerlo.

Dejo aquí la respuesta por si puede servir a alguien en el futuro:

```
ssh -vvv usuario@ip-remota -L 3307:localhost:3306 -N -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.dms -f
```

Esta parte: **`~/.ssh/id_rsa.dms`** sería la ruta y el nombre del archivo.

Comment: Es más cómodo si todas esas opciones las pones en `.ssh/config` definiendo un nombre de sesión que las use (`man ssh_config`). De ese modo en línea de comandos basta poner `ssh nombre_sesion`